# How to use html text just on homepage

Tags: php, html, css

I have some HTML and I make design and everything ok, I tried to put this text in the footer but the problem is this text showing on all pages and I need show this text just at the homepage, can u pls explain to me how I can do it !!

```html
<div class="footer-margin">
  {{if $footer_hide_advertisement!='true'}}
  <div class="content">
    ================== HERE MY HTML TEXT ============= 
    {{insert name="getAdv" place_id="spot_footer"}}
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footer-wrap">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.home}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_home}}</a></li>
      {{if $lang.enable_memberzone=='true'}} {{if $smarty.session.user_id>0}}
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.memberzone_my_profile}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_profile}}</a></li>
      {{assign var="fav_videos_count" value=$smarty.session.favourite_videos_summary[0].amount|default:0}}
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.memberzone_my_fav_videos[0]}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_fav_videos|count_format:"%1%":$fav_videos_count}}</a></li>
      {{if $lang.enable_albums=='true'}} {{assign var="fav_albums_count" value=$smarty.session.favourite_albums_summary[0].amount|default:0}}
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.memberzone_my_fav_albums[0]}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_fav_albums|count_format:"%1%":$fav_albums_count}}</a></li>
      {{/if}} {{else}}
      <li><a data-href="{{$lang.urls.signup}}" data-fancybox="ajax">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_signup}}</a></li>
      <li><a data-href="{{$lang.urls.login}}" data-fancybox="ajax">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_login}}</a></li>
      {{/if}} {{/if}}
      <li><a data-href="{{$lang.urls.feedback}}" data-fancybox="ajax">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_support}}</a></li>
      {{if $lang.enable_static_terms=='true'}}
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.terms}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_terms}}</a></li>
      {{/if}} {{if $lang.enable_static_dmca=='true'}}
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.dmca}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_dmca}}</a></li>
      {{/if}} {{if $lang.enable_static_2257=='true'}}
      <li><a href="{{$lang.urls.2257}}">{{$lang.footer.primary_menu_2257}}</a></li>
      {{/if}}
    </ul>
    <div class="copyright">
      {{$lang.footer.copyright_year}}-{{$smarty.now|date_format:"%Y"}} <a href="{{$lang.urls.home}}">{{$lang.project_name}}</a><br/> {{$lang.footer.copyright_text}}

    </div>
    <div class="txt">
      {{$lang.footer.site_text}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <p>
    <a href="http://rtalabel.org/?content=validate&amp;rating=RTA-5042-1996-1400-1577-RTA"> <img style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" src="https://sextime.tv/88x31_RTA-5042-1996-1400-1577-RTA-L-VERIFIED.gif" alt="Verified RTA member" /></a>
  </p>
  <script src="{{$config.statics_url}}/static/js/main.min.js?v=8.5"></script>
  <script>
    $.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS = {
      cursor: 'wait'
    };

    {
      {
        if $lang.search_suggestions.type != 'none'
      }
    }
    $.Autocomplete.defaults.minChars = 3;
    $.Autocomplete.defaults.deferRequestBy = 100;
    $.Autocomplete.defaults.serviceUrl = '{{$lang.urls.search_suggestions}}'; {
      {
        if $lang.search_suggestions.type == 'mixed'
      }
    }
    $.Autocomplete.defaults.groupBy = 'type'; {
      {/if}} {
          {/if}}
  </script>
  {{if $recaptcha_site_key!=''}}
  <script>
    function recaptchaOnLoad() {
      $(document).trigger('recaptchaloaded');
    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=recaptchaOnLoad&render=explicit"></script>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

Comment: Which platform are you using ?
Some platforms are designed to put the footer for every page.

You can just put your text in another specific TAB instead in the footer, and that way this TAB will show only on your homepage.

Comment: Im using KVS script, pls at my  Question again, update it

Comment: Your question is not understandable. You just dump some template on us. Please read [ask]

Comment: brother, as i told u, im very noob with coding and how to ask, but as I told you, I need to put text at the homepage in the footer and show this just at the homepage, and this code is what I'm using to put the HTML code inside

Comment: I don’t know what “KVS script” is, and a quick search is only showing Kernel Video Sharing, is that what this is?